# Unable to create with packages in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to create package in Android Studio and under packages I am creating different activities, but when I try to create package that package automatically combine with other package. I.e.: I am creating package name of allActs but it combines with already defined package i.e.: android.com.forecastnearthquake.allActs. Can anyone tell me how to create separate package?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: your child package don`t have a any class inside package so your package merge with main package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a single subpackage, with all classes within. If you want to see two packages, then make a new one and type out the full package name

Or Click the gear icon on the top right of that panel.

Select option to not collapse empty packages

Comment: Where is that gear icon ? I am not seeing

Comment: I clicked on gear icon but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

There is trick I use when this happens:

1. Create new activity where you want the new package.
2. In package line, add the new package name you want, to generate a error (java) or warning (kotlin).
3. Use `alt + enter` (windows) and select the option: `Move to package x.y.z`

[Click here to see how option is on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kP1P.png)

Answer (score 0):

Click the gear icon on the top right of that panel.

Select option **"Tree Apearance"**, uncheck the item **"Compact Middle Packages"**.
Done!